# How to program Android App in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I want to program an Android Application in Visual Studio 2015. I have Visual Studio Professional 2015 and i installed Xamarin. But when i creat a new Blank Android App I see this one and I can't program it How can I solve it ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the documentation for this?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn879698(v=vs.140).aspx  - this one is technical

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/xamarin-vs.aspx

Have a look here. Hope this helps. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You just created a project and you can start programing it. Please have a look at [this link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/). It describes a quickstart to create android apps.

Change to VisualStudio in the upper right corner of the website to see the solution for VisualStudio.

Have fun =)